# What are the simplest examples of nonlinear statistical functionals?

Tags: estimators, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn, functional-data-analysis

I am reading Wasserman's book "All of Statistics" in which he defines a statistical functional as any function $T(F)$ of the cumulative distribution function $F(x)$ that outputs a real number. Then he goes on to define a 'linear statistical functional' as a functional $T$ for which the following condition holds:

$$T(aF+bG) = aT(F) + bT(G)$$

where $F$ and $G$ are CDFs, and $a, b$ are constants. Obviously the functionals like the mean and variance are linear. What are some examples of "nonlinear statistical functionals"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Variances. Per [the Wikipedia page on mixture distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution), expectations *are* linear, but variances are not. (When you think about it, this is kind of obvious, because expectations involve integrating over a function, which is linear, but variances involve integrating over the *square* of a function, which isn't.)

  Specifically, for $n$ mixture components with means $\mu_i$, variances $\sigma_i^2$ and mixture weights $w_i$ summing to one, we have a mixture mean and variance of
  $$ \begin{align*}
  \mu =& \sum_{i=1}^n w_i\mu_i \\
  \sigma^2 =& \sum_{i=1}^n w_i(\sigma_i^2+\mu_i^2-\mu^2).
  \end{align*}$$
  The expression for $\sigma^2$ is quite different from $\sum w_i\sigma_i^2$ because of the *squared* means. For instance, consider two normals $N(0,1)$ and $N(1,2)$ with weights $(0.3,0.7)$, then
  $$ \begin{align*}
  \mu =& w_1\mu_1+w_2\mu_2 = 0.7 \\
  \sigma^2 =& w_1(\sigma_1^2+\mu_1^2-\mu^2)+w_2(\sigma_2^2+\mu_2^2-\mu^2) = 1.91
  \neq 1.7 = w_1\sigma_1^2+w_2\sigma_2^2.
  \end{align*}$$

  Here is a quick R simulation for people who (like me) don't trust my math-fu:

  ```
  weights <- c(0.3,0.7)
  means <- c(0,1)
  vars <- c(1,2)

  index <- 2-(runif(1e7)<weights[1])
  sims <- rnorm(length(which_one),mean=means[index],sd=sqrt(vars[index]))

  mean(sims)
  sum(weights*means)

  var(sims)
  sum(weights*vars)
  ```
- Quantiles. For instance, your CDFs could be normal distributions with different means and variances, so $aF+bG$ would be a Gaussian mixture, and $T$ could extract any quantile. Quantiles of mixtures are not simply the weighted averages of the quantiles of the components. ([See here for an argument why the median is not a linear functional for mixtures of normal distributions.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/523417/1352))
- The maximum or minimum of distributions with bounded support. If your two CDFs are for a $U[0,1]$ and a $U[0,2]$ distribution and $a,b>0$, then the mixture will have minimum $0$ and maximum $2$, regardless of the specific values of $a$ and $b$. Yes, this is not all that different from quantiles.
- The (-1)-median, which is the functional that minimizes the expected [mean absolute percentage error](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/1352), and is not very well known.

Comment: Thanks! Are there other similarly obvious ones?

Comment: Well, the min and the max of bounded distributions are really special cases of quantiles. I can also offer the (-1)-median, which is rather unknown.

Comment: Why do you bring up the (-1)-median when you’re so down on MAPE? (I follow your arguments for why MAPE is flawed, but I wonder why (-1)-median is interesting despite the flaws of MAPE.)

Comment: @Dave: I wouldn't say I'm *down* on the MAPE. It's used a lot, even if I personally am not very fond of it. But simply because it's widely used, I like to know that there is a particular functional that optimizes it, even if the definition of the (-1)-median is really nothing more than "that thing that optimizes the MAPE". Besides, dropping that name is sometimes a good conversation opener. (Among the right kind of people.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa : What about the simplest of the quantiles, the median? Is it a nonlinear statistical functional?

Comment: @Peaceful: yes, certainly. That's covered in my first bullet point.

Comment: @StephanKolassa : Do you know an explicit way to prove that linearity is impossible in general? An example perhaps? Consider a valid CDF $H(x)=aF(x)+(1-a)G(x)$ with $a\in[0,1]$. Now if $T(H)=x_M$, the median, then how would we prove that $x_M = a\mu_1+(1-a)\mu_2$ is impossible? Here $F$ and $G$ are Gaussian CDFS with means $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$